# XPath: How to extract several Values of repeating Elements (Collection) (in PHP)?

Tags: php, xpath

Given the following example code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="val1">foo</div>
  <div class="val2">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="val1">foo</div>
  <div class="val2">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="val1">foo</div>
  <div class="val2">bar</div>
</div>
```

**What would one single(!) XPath expression have to look like, to get out an PHP array/collection like the following**:

`array( array(val1=>foo,val2=>bar), array(val1=>foo,val2=>bar), array(val1=>foo,val2=>bar))`

**Or is the only solution doing this in two steps**

```
//div[@class=row]
```

and then iterating over this result and feeding this to a new xpath query and then doing

```
//div[@class=val1]
//div[@class=val2]
```

So my questoin is related to extracting repeating elements with lots of subvalues with one xpath expression, something like is possible with regular expressions capturing groups... Thanks!